Pagination in AWS DynamoDB by arbitrary page number
I am creating a DynamoDB Scan lambda triggered by an AWS Api Gateway and I am trying to implement pagination. I understand that, in order to do it, I need to send a LastEvaluatedKey in the response and than use that key for ExclusiveStartKey.
However, this way, I cannot implement something like a section to select the page, since I would never know how many pages and what products are on each page (I would need to get items of page 1 to know were page 2 starts).
How can I solve this problem and search for items of specific pages?
Here's a very simplified version of the lambda function:
import { DynamoDBClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, ScanCommand, type ScanCommandInput } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';
import { type Handler, type APIGatewayProxyEvent, type APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';

const client = new DynamoDBClient();
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

export const handler: Handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    const { queryStringParameters } = event;
    try {
        const page = queryStringParameters?.page || 1; // Get the page number from the query string parameters
        const pageSize = 5;

        // Define the parameters for the scan operation
        const params: ScanCommandInput = {
            TableName: 'Products',
            Limit: pageSize,
            ExclusiveStartKey: exclusiveStartKey // how to define exclusiveStartKey?
        };

        const { Items, LastEvaluatedKey } = await docClient.send(new ScanCommand(params));
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                products: Items,
                nextPage: LastEvaluatedKey ? Number(page) + 1 : null // how to define nextPage?
            })
        };
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle errors
    }
};


DynamoDB is not a complex database, and the very fact that you're creating an API using a Scan API makes me wonder why your using DynamoDB at all.
Based on your access pattern and the need to decide on which pay to go to, perhaps a relational database over a NoSQL one would suit best....
If your content is static you could give it a partition key of page number, that way whatever page you go to you'll be able to do so efficiently and get the exact same results each time.

I appreciate you suggesting me the best way you think I should follow and I’ll take that into consideration. So actually there isn’t any conventional way of solving this problem that you have knowledge of, speaking of just DynamoDB?

Not really, DynamoDB is really fast at accessing the data at point x in a range of values, but it's not optimized for accessing point x + n_items
